# Why Can't I Use Template Literals to Create Strings as Keys In a New Object? 

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

I have some *Array* of *Objects,* with a sample *Object* as such:

```js
{
    id: 10,
    name: "Clementina XYZ",
    username: "Moriah.Stanton",
    email: "foo.bar@quux.biz",
    address: {
      street: "Kattie Turnpike",
      suite: "Suite 555",
      city: "Lebsackbury",
      zipcode: "31428-2261",
      geo: {
        lat: "-38.2386",
        lng: "57.2232"
      }
    },
    phone: "555-648-3804",
    website: "example.com",
    company: {
      name: "Acme LLC",
      catchPhrase: "Centralized empowering task-force",
      bs: "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
```

I also have a *function* that is working just fine to find `user`s that work in the same `company.name` and `map` over them to create *Objects* with `name`, `address` and `phone`.

```js
function buildCompanyDirectory(company, directory) {
  return directory
    .filter(user => user.company.name === company)
    .map(({ name, address, phone }) => ({
      name,
      address,
      phone
    }));
}
```

Now, a new task:

`// TODO: Build an Array of company directories`

So, I expect to have a final *Array* consisting of s that are derived from `user.company.name` with *values* that are *Arrays* of *Objects* with s of `name`, `address` and `phone`. So, something like:

```js
[{
  "Hoeger LLC": [{ }]
}]
```

As part of solving this, I feel (evidently JS doesn't agree!) that I should be able to use *template literals* to create new *objects* using s that are derived from the *values* from another *object.*

That nonworking code looks like this:

```js
const directories = users.map((user) => {
  return {
    `${user.company.name}` : buildCompanyDirectory(company.name, users) // ERROR: Property assignment expected
  };
});
```

It doesn't seem that I should need to resort to `Object.keys()` or anything like that. This feels more like some type of 'syntax' error or just bad notation.

Naturally, I would like to know the simplest way to get this working out! Thanks.

Comment: Posting real people's detail in code examples is uncool. Edited them out.

Comment: It's not real people. It's fake sample data from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: Good to know, thanks! It was so good, hard to tell from real data though %)

Comment: No biggie. It's all fake, so edits won't affect any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that key construction in object literals is special-cased in JS. You can use either a literal string or a bare identifier.

To allow an expression as a key in an object literal, JS uses the following hack:

```js
const a = 'aaaa';
const data = {[`this_is_${a}`]: 10}
data.this_is_aaaa === 10; // true.
```

The expression within `[]` will be evaluated and used as a key.